# Can I speed up UAC/elevation in WiX?

Tags: installation, wix, uac, elevation

When a normal user runs a WiX installer which requires elevation, there appears to be a delay of 30 seconds or more between the user clicks the "Install" button and the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt comes up. This happens even though the install button is marked with the UAC shield, suggesting the installer "knows" that elevation will be required.

Is there a way to IMMEDIATELY throw up the UAC when the user 1) runs the installer or 2) clicks that "Install" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of time for the UAC prompt to come up depends on the size of the exe. (Try it yourself by right-click run as admin various exes of various sizes.) Therefore I have heard it suggested that you make a teeny launcher exe that will bring the prompt up quickly, and have it launch everything else. Anything launched from an elevated process is elevated.

Be sure to name your launcher well, for the 1% of users who actually read the UAC prompts.

Comment: That assumes you have a setup.exe with a manifest to ask for elevation.  In the case of a Windows Installer file without one, elevation occurs when you click Install and transition from the Install's UI sequence to the Install's Execute Sequence. ( This assumes you've set Bit 3 of the Word Count Summary in the summary information stream to 1 )

Answer (score 1):

How big is your MSI file? I don't know for a fact, but I think splitting your files into a separate .cab file and possibly digitally signing it might make the validation of the MSI file go faster.

Otherwise, there really isn't anything you can do about it to my knowledge. I hope someone proves me wrong. :-)